# Get subset of array and list from list of index

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a numpy array `X` and a python list `y` whose elements correspond. I have a partial list of indexes which I would like to use to form another array `refinedX` and `refinedY.`

For example, if the partial list contained `0,1` and `X=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` and `y=[1,2,1]`, I want `refiendX = [[1,2], [3,4]]` and `refinedY = [1,2].`

How can I do this in python?

Note: The actual variable X is a (2000,5000) matrix and the partial list will contain around 500 items.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some code that does the job.

```
X=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
Y=[1,2,1]
indexes = [1,2]
refinedX = [X[i-1] for i in indexes]
refinedY = [Y[i-1] for i in indexes]
```

If you will regularly update indexes this may be resource heavy so in that case I'd suggest to use this instead:

```
X[indexes[i]-1] #instead of refinedX[i]
```

for each time you call a certain value.